# How to add Contribution By column

Tags: civievent

My use case is that I want users to be able to pay for another user's Event Participation.

Currently, the display name is baked into the source: [image]

I'm hoping to add a column "Contribution By" to record a link to this person instead.

How can I add a column into this table?

Comment: Hey John, Just to add a little more info to this ticket - there is the registered by field which is populated when multiple registrations are made by a single contact. Is that the scenario your talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I'd wager that the template you're looking at calls [hook_civicrm_searchColumns](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/stable/hooks/hook_civicrm_searchColumns/).  Despite the name referring to "search", it's designed to let you change the values of the columns in tables like the one you display.

I just pushed a simple extension that demonstrates how it's used: https://github.com/PalanteJon/org.takethestreets.campaignincontributiontab/blob/master/campaignincontributiontab.php

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am totally following your question. But... have you looked at Soft Credits? 
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/contributions/soft-credits/

Comment: Thanks for responding Carl. This isn't about that. This is modifying a template file to show more information than is stored.